# Why is Android O failing with “does not belong to this FragmentManager!”

Tags: android

I have migrated my application to Android O in Android Studio 3

Running on an Android O emulator all my dialogFragments now fail with :-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment CustomAlertDialogFragment{41cfde98 #0 dialog} declared target fragment LayoutOne{41e7f970 #0 id=0x7f0d0207 android:switcher:2131558919:0} that does not belong to this FragmentManager!
```

I am getting error in the following code:-

```
 Modules.showDialog(bundledialog, DIALOG_FOUND, this, getChildFragmentManager());

public static void showDialog(Bundle bundle, int type, Fragment fragment, FragmentManager manager)
{
    CustomAlertDialogFragment diag=new CustomAlertDialogFragment();
    diag.setTargetFragment(fragment, type);
    diag.setArguments(bundle);
    try {
        diag.show(manager, "dialog");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Calling **Modules.showDialog(bundledialog, DIALOG_FOUND, this, getChildFragmentManager());** means you're willing to show the **current fragment** (which uses the regular getFragmentManager()) with help of the **getChildFragmentManager()**. Try replacing **getChildFragmentManager()** with **getFragmentManager()**

Comment: i need to add                             if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){

Comment: or not........................

Answer (score 1):

It happens when you are showing a fragment from another fragment using it as target. As workaround you can use:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(dialogFrag, "dialog").commit();
} else {
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(dialogFrag, "dialog").commit();
}
```